# Getting Object does not support this action error on $.post

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Here's my javascript method:

```
function AssignDebtor(e) {
        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
        var debtorId = dataItem.Id;

        $.post({
            url: '@Url.Action("AssignDebtorToUnallocatedReceipt", "Debtor")',
            data: new { unallocatedReceiptId : cdcUnallocatedReceiptId, debtorId : debtorId },
            success: function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                if (result.success) {
                    var window = $("#LookupDebtorWindow").data("kendoWindow");
                    window.close();

                    var grid = $("#UnallocatedReceiptsGrid").data("kendoGrid");
                    grid.dataSource.read();
                }
                else {
                    alert(result.error);
                }
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
```

At runtime, the debugger stops on the $.post line, and returns this error:

> 0x800a01bd - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this
>   action

debtorId successfully gets its value.  Is there perhaps a problem in the way I have constructed the method?

Comment: Do you have jquery linked?

Comment: Does it happen inside your success function, or just the post declaration itself?

Comment: @JohnEcho yes jquery is linked because the code certainly would not have gotten as far as it has without jquery (using Kendo UI - This method is what gets executed after clicking a custom grid command button)

Comment: @mattytommo it's at the post declaration itself.

Comment: why do you test for result.success (shouldn't it be jqXHR.success anyway) in the success handler ?

Comment: @jbl: That `success` is a property of the server response; the server might also answer that the action could not be executed. The `jqXHR.error` callback would signal that there was a http error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new { unallocatedReceiptId : cdcUnallocatedReceiptId, debtorId : debtorId }
```

looks like a syntax error, but is none unfortunately. Instead, it throws that exception you get when you try to use an object (which is not even a function at all) as a constructor.

Just omit the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

Also, as @danludwig mentioned, the [`$.post` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) has a different signature, you cannot pass in an object as a parameter. Rather switch to `$.ajax`.

Answer (score 2):

`$.post` does not allow you to pass in a javascript object, it expects more strongly-typed method parameters. [See the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) and try this instead:

```
function AssignDebtor(e) {
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    var debtorId = dataItem.Id;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("AssignDebtorToUnallocatedReceipt", "Debtor")',
        data: { unallocatedReceiptId : cdcUnallocatedReceiptId, debtorId : debtorId },
        success: function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (result.success) {
                var window = $("#LookupDebtorWindow").data("kendoWindow");
                window.close();

                var grid = $("#UnallocatedReceiptsGrid").data("kendoGrid");
                grid.dataSource.read();
            }
            else {
                alert(result.error);
            }
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

... or if you are partial to `$.post`, you could do this instead:

```
function AssignDebtor(e) {
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    var debtorId = dataItem.Id;

    $.post('@Url.Action("AssignDebtorToUnallocatedReceipt", "Debtor")',
        { unallocatedReceiptId : cdcUnallocatedReceiptId, debtorId : debtorId },
        function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (result.success) {
                var window = $("#LookupDebtorWindow").data("kendoWindow");
                window.close();

                var grid = $("#UnallocatedReceiptsGrid").data("kendoGrid");
                grid.dataSource.read();
            }
            else {
                alert(result.error);
            }
        },
        'json'
     );
}
```

Note I also took out the `new` keyword from your parameters object.

Comment: No object has a name, all are "anonymous". What exactly did you change in the code?

Comment: @Bergi ok I won't argue, I removed 'anonymous' and replaced with 'javascript object'. I changed it from `$.post` to `$.ajax`. There is also an alternative that uses `$.post` with separate <del>method</del> function arguments.